# Login Parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

**Issue:** People can still see all the pages but 2 (it's a small site so not a ton of pages) when not logged in and I need to redirect pages to the login page when it's clicked. The code I have is the following:

---

```js
// Intercept 401s and redirect you to login
  responseError: function(response) {
    if (response.status === 401, 403) {
      (state || (state = $injector.get('$state'))).go('login');
      // remove any stale tokens
      $cookies.remove('token');
      return $q.reject(response);
    }
    else {
      return $q.reject(response);
    }
  }
};
  })
  
.run(function($rootScope, $state, Auth) {
    // Redirect to login if route requires auth and the user is not logged in
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, next) {
      if (next.authenticate) {
        Auth.isLoggedIn(function(loggedIn) {
          if (!loggedIn) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $state.go('login');
```

I know it's supposed to forward/ redirect but I'm not sure if it's the code itself on the app.js page or if i need to comb through the pages individually and change them. Anyone know if I need to insert something?

Comment: You have a module for that (https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth) all you need to do is returen http error code 403 for unauthorized request, and it will trigger a global event that you catch in your code and redirect the user to the login page

Comment: @stark I'm pretty sure I have that, this is mine:                                                    // Intercept 401s and redirect you to login
      responseError: function(response) {
        if (response.status === 401, 403) {
          (state || (state = $injector.get('$state'))).go('login');
          // remove any stale tokens
          $cookies.remove('token');
          return $q.reject(response);
        }
        else {
          return $q.reject(response);
        }
      }
    };
  })

Comment: p.s. I'm a novice so sorry ahead of time lol